# Export data to a word template

Tags: apex, visualforce, data-export, mail-merge

Is there a way I can export to a word document?  I have a fair amount of government (difficult to change) forms that are auto-filled out by a legacy system.  It's high value to the users to be able to have SalesForce populate the Word documents.

I see there is something called Conga but there is an extra cost.  I'd prefer to either used a pre-made native functionality or write something myself at no cost.

Ideally, we'd upload a template with merged fields then have the ability to export that document from a record with the fields filled out.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a visualforce page and set the content type (one of the attributes on the `<apex:page>` tag)

Here's some example code (not mine, no guarantees!)
http://salesforcecat.blogspot.com/2014/11/render-visualforce-page-as-word-document.html

When you load the page, you'll get a browser download.  If you wanted to store the file instead, you can generate the page in apex and save that BLOB as an attachment.

Comment: So I would have to recreate all of the word docs in visualforce?  I was hoping to upload a template with merge fields and then export in some fashion.  This way it wouldn't require a developer everytime there was a form change.  Also, the process for these complicated forms could be very cumbersome to mock-up.

Comment: This is a perfect example:  http://www.congamerge.com/use-cases/examples/invoices-receipts

Comment: yep, that's why Conga, Drawloop, etc exist.  You're paying a bit, but saving a huge amount of developer work.

Comment: Yeah buying seems better than building here. Recreating Word documents seems...non-trivial.

Comment: Do you think XMM (extended mail merge) would do what we're after?

Comment: XMM: possibly.  But it only supports a few objects, and a few browsers.  Might work for a very, very circumscribed use case.

Comment: Conga (or Drawloop) is the answer.  You will save so much time by editing in Word your templates than trying to rebuild in VF with endless fighting in CSS world.